# How to checking a folder with loop and maxattempts using POwershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to check a folder, if not exist after max attempt it will restart the computer.
I tried this but the maxattempt looks not working
Anyone can help really appreciate. Thanks

```
$MaxAttempts = 2
$n = 0
while ($true) {
    $n++
    $folder = Get-ChildItem -Directory "D:\*"
    if ($folder -or $n -gt $MaxAttempts){
        Write-Host Found
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Not FOund after maxattempt"
        Restart-Computer
    }
}
```

#### updated

This is work

```
$count = 0
$maxTries = 10
$logToFind = "D:\"
$logFound = $false
do {
    Write-Output "Checking for $logToFind"    
    If (Test-Path -Path "$logToFind\*") {
        Write-Output "Found $logToFind"
        $count = 0
        $logFound = $true
        break
    } Else {
        Write-Output 'Not found'
        If ($count -lt ($maxTries - 1)) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        }
        $count++
    }
} While ($count -lt $maxTries)
If ($logFound) {
    Write-Output "$logToFind was found during the test."
} 
Else {
    Write-Output "$logToFind was NOT found during the test."
    Restart-Computer
}
```

Comment: I am note sure about "D:\*" is it a single folder in D: drive?

Answer (score 2):

Adjusted based on your comments. This will complete as per your request.

```
$maxAttempts = 2
$n = 1

Do {
    If((Test-Path D:\) -and ($n -le $maxAttempts)) {
        Write-Output "Found after $n attempts"
        break
    } Elseif(-not (Test-Path D:\) -and ($n -gt $maxAttempts)) {
        Write-Output "Not Found after $n attempts"
        Restart-Computer
        break
    }
    $n++
}While($True)
```

Comment: But I dont want to limited the total of the folder, It doesn not matter how many folder in the path. Thats what I need actually. Could you please give idea?

Comment: @SBR You want to check if the folder exists at all?

Comment: Yes, Just checking the folder. After looping 5 times(configable), and its not exist, it will restart the computer @Drew